# What does ":?" after a method means in PHP?

Tags: php, php-7

I just saw this in a Symfony 4 application, and I can't find nowhere what it means

```
  public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Article
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
```

I know that, now with PHP 7 you can define the expected type of the returned value with **":int $val"**, but here, what does the **?** symbol means ?

Comment: it probably means the return type is null or Article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature as of PHP 7.1. See the explanation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.

This means the expected output of your function will be either an Instance of the class `Article` or it is `NULL`.

Comment: In the future you should close questions asking about symbols in PHP as a duplicate of the question above.